# How do you find semi-stable fixed points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the derivative at a fixed point is negative, it’s stable. If it’s positive, it’s unstable. What would be observed for a semi-stable fixed point? How do you general find semi-stable fixed points without looking at the graph?

Answer (score 0):

For a semi-stable fixed point in a smooth dynamical system (i.e. no discontinuities), you'd find the derivative at that fixed point to be equal to $0$.

This is because the semi-stable nature of the fixed point has to be explained through higher-order derivatives, since linearized dynamics around a fixed point can never capture semi-stability due to the very nature of linear functions.

Finding them is usually associated with noting that a fixed point possesses a trivial linearization, followed by a higher-order analysis of the derivatives there.